# jQuery Isotope plugin won't sort selected elements to top left

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to sort these elements using the jQuery [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) plugin. I can't get my selected option to align to the top left, it just moves to the bottom of the grid. I looked at the sortAscending option, but it ruins the order I placed my content in. Is there something I'm missing? Here's a demo of my work: http://jsfiddle.net/Yvk9q/3/

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is too simple, but they way the `getSortData` option was working was just doing everything backwards, so I added 3 exclamation marks before isMilk?, isBacon?, , and isEggs?.  It looks good now:

http://jsfiddle.net/Yvk9q/9/

Comment: Very nice! I will upvote for you. Out of interest...is it possible to make the actual items clickable so they jump to the top left?